# Desplazamiento de bits

Tags: java

tengo este código:

```
public class Borrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 2;
        System.out.println(m << 1);
    }
}
```

Lo que yo entiendo es que m es igual a 2, es decir representándolo en 4 bits sería 0100. Entonces si desplazo un bit hacia la izquierda 0100 <- 0 = 1000 me quedaría esto no? Entonces por qué el programa imprime 4 cuando según mis cálculos debería de imprimir 1?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: 2 no es 0100, es 0010. El programa está bien. Si desplazas 1 hacia la izquierda, te da 0100 que es 4

Comment: Lo estaba haciendo al revés, que descuido. Ya decía yo. Muchas gracias